# Values attribute on parameters passed into method

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

Recently, I saw method like this

```
public void MyMethod([Values("One", "Two", "Three")] string order, [Values(true, false)] bool choice)
{
    // ...
}
```

I have never seen this before.  What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Is that a test method? [NUnit uses those in its testing framework](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Values-Attribute). Here's a hint for searching: If you see an attribute with "Name" do a search for "NameAttribute". That's the general pattern for naming attribute classes in C#.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan.  You were right.  I cannot mark your comment as an answer.  Can you make it into an answer and I'll mark it.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is used in a test method, I know [NUnit uses those in its testing framework](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Values-Attribute). From the linked page:

> The ValuesAttribute is used to specify a set of values to be provided for an individual parameter of a parameterized test method.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCoughan